# meshgrid with 2d array as input

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D array of floats, each cell representing a magnitude at the col/row of said array and would like to create a surface plot and contour for it.

How do I use meshgrid on this 2D array?

My apologies for this simple - I am new to both Python and numpy.

Comment: Do you have some sample data?  Is the data continuous in the X and Y direction or does it represent a potentiall sparse surface such as might be obtained by sampling elevation using a random versus systematic sampling strategy?

Comment: Thank you.  I had a discrepancy between the number of cols/lines of my 2D array and the X, Y vectors.  This was because I skipped the header of the .CSV file I was acquiring the data from, where said CSV did not have a header.  All fixed and working nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# Generate fake data
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.exp(-(X**2 + Y**2))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.05, color="w")
ax1.contour(X, Y, Z, zorder=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

All these functions are described in the [mplot3d tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#contour-plots)